# How to disable JIRA mobile interface on my JIRA Instance?

Tags: mobile, jira, confluence, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

Can anyone let me know how to disable JIRA mobile interface on my instance as i dont want users to switch to mobile version and want them to view the desktop interface on their mobile phones.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I don't believe Atlassian offers that setting. Users can switch to the Desktop view from their mobile menu, but aside from device browser settings, I believe that is the only option you have.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I am answering my question as found out the answer - We can disable JIRA mobile for your site, so that users will only be able to access the desktop view of JIRA on their mobile device.

JIRA mobile is a implemented as a add-on in JIRA, so you can disable it by disabling the add-on. For instructions on disabling add-ons, seeManaging Add-ons. Note, JIRA mobile is a System Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
**Can I disable JIRA mobile for my site?**

You can disable JIRA mobile for your site, so that users will only be able 
to access the desktop view of JIRA on their mobile device.
JIRA mobile is a implemented as a add-on in JIRA, so you can disable it by 
disabling the add-on. For instructions on disabling add-ons, see Managing 
Add-ons. Note, JIRA mobile is a System Plugin.
```

I found this in : https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/using-jira-on-a-mobile-device-720416174.html

But I cannot find the Plugin in my Jira 6.4...

SO it's best of you to switch it in mobile.